# What is the "Rails way" to handle alternative instructions after User Sign-up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a Rails 4 application for learning purposes.  I need advice about Rails best practices.  My sign up form has the following fields: "User_name", "email", "password", and "confirmation".  It also has two (boolean) check boxes: "workout_enthusiast" and "personal_trainer".  BTW... My application also has Member and Trainer models. There are two kinds of users:  members and trainers.

When a new user signs up, I want to feed the result from the two check boxes to the Users controller so that its "create method" sends the new user to a page that contains one set of instructions for next steps for users who are gym-goers - - workout enthusiasts :) and another set of instructions for personal trainers. In other words, I want a Welcome page that is "dynamically rendered" based on the check box input.

I'm not satisfied with my first attempt to address the issue.  In users/show.html.erb, I placed the following code:

```
<div class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
<p>
   <strong>Workout enthusiast or fitness buff? Complete your <%= link_to 'Member Profile', new_member_path %> now!</strong>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Personal trainer or fitness coach? Complete your <%= link_to 'Trainer Profile', new_trainer_path %> now!</strong>
</p>
</div>
```

This "hard coded in the show view" approach doesn't solve the issue, because the instructions "persist" after a user completes the profile. That's unacceptable; I don't want users to be asked to visit the Profile form if they've already completed that step in the registration process.

I thought about trying to solve the problem by using a flash message, but I don't know if that's the best way to handle the situation.  Skinny Controller/Brittle View?  Here's relevant code from my Users Controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    log_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
    redirect_to @user
 else
   render 'new'
  end
end
```

I want to learn the "Rails way," so I'm asking.  What is the most appropriate way to handle this scenario?

I appreciate any guidance and advice!

Comment: there is no "Rails" way to do this because this is an application-specific requirement.  You have to decide what you want to do and how you want the application to behave after sign up.  If you want to redirect users depending on what they chose on sign up, then do that in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set yoir flash message on the basis of your boolean value. Like

> flash[:success]=true/false

Then check this value on your show view.

> if flash[:success] == true

And show your relevant data on show page.

Comment: Dipak - thanks for your reply. I don't understand your advice about a flash message solution. I tried to edit my Controller code, but couldn't get it to work. Please clarify. Where does the flash message go? Where do I put the text of the alternative instructions to members & trainers? I'm not understanding how I need to change my User controller to see if the solution works? Thanks for your help!